# Unable to access value i inside function onSelect of autoComplete. [Dynamically generate jquery]

Tags: javascript, autocomplete

Cannot get the value of i inside onSelect. Im calling the below jQuery function in a loop. I need the value of i to populate data in onSelect.
Is there a better way to generate jquery? Please help me on this.

```
for (i = count; i > 1; i--) {
      jQuery(function ($) {
        $(`input[name="company${i}"]`).autoComplete({
          minChars: 1,
          source: function (term, response) {
            $.getJSON('https://autocomplete.clearbit.com/v1/companies/suggest', {
              query: term
            }, function (data) {
              response(data);
            });
          },
          renderItem: function (item, search) {
            default_logo = 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/clearbit-blog/images/company_autocomplete_api/unknown.gif'

            if (item.logo == null) {
              logo = default_logo
            } else {
              logo = item.logo + '?size=25'
            }

            container = '<div class="autocomplete-suggestion" data-name="' + item.name + '" data-val="' + search + '">'
            container += '<span class="icon"><img align="center" src="' + logo + '" onerror="this.src=\'' + default_logo + '\'"></span> '
            container += item.name + '<span class="domain">' + item.domain + '</span></div>';
            return container
          },
          onSelect: function (e, term, item) {
            $(`input[name="company${i}"]`).val(item.data('name'))
          },
        });
      });
    }
```

Comment: are you getting 'undefined' for "i" in the onSelect function?

Answer (score 1):

You have several problems in this code:

`jQuery(function ($) {` will execute when all resources have been loaded, by that time the `for` loop has ended (because it's outside the `ready` function) and `i` will have its last value so it won't bind to all your elements. This function is acting as a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures#Closure), this is why you can't get the expected value in `onSelect`. Also, the loop will never get to 1, since the condition is `i > 1` and it should be `i > 0`.

You can move the `for` inside the `ready` function and scope the element of the current iteration, but I'm choosing a jQuery approach here using [`.each`](https://api.jquery.com/each/).

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $(`input[name^="company"]`).each(function() {
    // This is what makes this work. 
    // If you use the 'for' you can set it to `input[name="company${i}"]`
    let $input = $(this);  
    $input.autoComplete({
      minChars: 1,
      source: function(term, response) {
        response([{
          "name": "Amazon",
          "domain": "amazon.com",
          "logo": "https://logo.clearbit.com/amazon.com"
        }, {
          "name": "Amanda",
          "domain": "iambaker.net",
          "logo": "https://logo.clearbit.com/iambaker.net"
        }]);
      },
      renderItem: function(item, search) {
        default_logo = 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/clearbit-blog/images/company_autocomplete_api/unknown.gif'

        if (item.logo == null) {
          logo = default_logo
        } else {
          logo = item.logo + '?size=25'
        }

        container = '<div class="autocomplete-suggestion" data-name="' + item.name + '" data-val="' + search + '">'
        container += '<span class="icon"><img align="center" src="' + logo + '" onerror="this.src=\'' + default_logo + '\'"></span> '
        container += item.name + '<span class="domain">' + item.domain + '</span></div>';
        return container
      },
      onSelect: function(e, term, item) {
        // Reference the current input element
        $input.val(item.data('name'))
      },
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-autocomplete/1.0.7/jquery.auto-complete.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-autocomplete/1.0.7/jquery.auto-complete.min.css" />
<input name="company1" />
<input name="company2" />
```

Comment: Ahh Thank You. Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

You should use let keyword with 'i' because as you are not using any keyword 'i' would remain in the global scope and when this onSelect event would fire, it would pick the latest value of 'i' at the moment of event fire which in your case would be 1. So your code should be

> for (let i = count; i > 1; i--){   // rest of the code reamins same }

Please read about

- [let, var and const](https://dzone.com/articles/javascript-difference-between-var-let-and-const-ke)
- [hosting](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_hoisting.asp)